# add_argument not working to enable dark mode in Google Chrome with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, darkmode, chrome-web-driver

I'm trying to launch Google Chrome with dark mode enabled using Selenium WebDriver in Python, but I'm having trouble getting the add_argument method to work. Here's the code I'm using:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--force-dark-mode')

driver = Chrome(options=chrome_options)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

When I run this code, it launches Google Chrome, but dark mode is not enabled. I've also tried using the --force-dark-mode-on but they didn't work either.

I'm using Google Chrome version 78, which should support the --force-dark-mode option. I'm not seeing any error messages or warnings in the console or logs.

What could be causing add_argument not to work for enabling dark mode in Google Chrome with Selenium WebDriver? Are there any other options or workarounds that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

### Chrome in dark mode

Not sure about ***Google Chrome version 78*** but using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.10.0*** with [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) / [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) ***v114.0*** [darkmode](/questions/tagged/darkmode) can be enforced using the argument:

```
options.add_argument('--force-dark-mode')
```

- Code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument('--force-dark-mode')
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: dark_mode]

---

### Web components in dark mode

Auto [darkmode](/questions/tagged/darkmode) for web contents can be enforced by using the argument:

```
options.add_argument("--enable-features=WebContentsForceDark")
```

- Code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("--enable-features=WebContentsForceDark")
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: enable-features=WebContentsForceDark]

Comment: Oops, I think I meant to say something else . (Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents)

Answer (score 0):

fix above code :

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-features=WebContentsForceDark")
```

and this is my command in chrome://version

Command Line:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --flag-switches-begin --enable-features=WebContentsForceDark --flag-switches-end --desktop-startup-id=gnome-shell/Google Chrome/some-info
```

For more information about command-line options in Google Chrome, you can check out the official [documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags%20%E2%86%97):

Comment: Which code is ***above code*** ?